# Network admin in wordpress is not allowed normal user admin panel

Tags: php, wordpress

Recently I have enabled multi-site (networking) in my existing wordpress.
by following instruction from http://codex.wordpress.org/Create_A_Network with sub-domain option.

Now it won't allow me to login for other users(user's does not have sub domain site) the username and password is correct but it does not  appear admin panel. Even if I type  `/wp-admin/` it leads me to login.

Please help !!!

NB: I enabled the multi site in an existing WordPress  site with existing users. Before enabling I can login in correctly with that existing user. But now I cannot login when WP_ALLOW_MULTISITE variable is true. if it is false then I can login

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that it was a plugin issue. i disabled all the plugins and set all from first. now it is working